# Attaching file to MS Graph email

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I understand how to use the MS Graph to send an email. I'm having issues attaching an email on a local workstation to the json message.  Most of the examples is how to retrieve from an existing message.

I see attachments but there is no way to calculate the size etc, and I don't see where to identify the file name and location.

Comment: {
  "message": {
    "subject": "Meet for lunch?",
    "body": {
      "contentType": "Text",
      "content": "The new cafeteria is open."
    },
    "toRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "meganb@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
      }
    ],
    "attachments": [
      {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
        "name": "attachment.txt",   <--- can one put the location on the local drive
        "contentType": "text/plain",
        "contentBytes": "SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh"  <-- how to calculate?

Comment: Also, how to specify email to be sent to 2 addresses

Comment: Hi there, could you add the detail to your question rather than including it as a comment.